# Tracking the delivery status after sending an iOS SMS from the app

Tags: ios, ios5, sms

I have a requirement to send an SMS to a set of user and track its delivery status. Is there any option available in iOS SDK to check whether the SMS is delivered successfully or not?

Thanks,
Adarsh

Comment: Nobody but the telco can track the delivery status of an SMS and even then it's iffy. It's a fire-and-forget protocol.

Comment: The iOS SMS app is able to receive a delivery report right? Is there any option to track that report and use it in our app?

Comment: Actually, the Messages app doesn't even support delivery reports on SMS (it only supports them on iMessage). Delivery report data is definitely not made available to apps.